# Page not displaying correctly in Firefox

Tags: firefox, menubar

I'm having trouble with an image slider and Menu bar that diplays correctly in IE and Chrome but is shifted to the right in Firefox.  This is only only for the Homepage, can anyone spot why?
http://www.mixing-mastering-online.com

Any help would really appreciated as I've trying differnt things for hours now but to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

from

```
.shadow
.sliderContainer
.slideshow
```

That fixes it. 
Please refer to the correct use of your css:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Thank you Patrick.  I tried this but it's still not working, I cleared the cache in Firefox also but it's still displayed with them shifted to the right.  Hopefully I can work it out via the information from the link, thanks for including it.

Comment: Thank you Patrick, I worked out where the actual code needed to be deleted from eventually.  I knew you had to be right so persisted in finding it.  You really helped me out!